# How to escape partially a template variable in Django

Tags: python, django, xss

I'm trying to highlight some text in the validation message of a Django admin form.

The result is something like this

```
  valid_part
  <span style="background-color:yellow">invalid_part</span> 
  another_valid_part
```

I would like to leave as is `<span ...>` and `</span>`, but the `valid_part`, `invalid_part` of what the user just entered should be escaped as to avoid XSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
#views.py
from django.utils.html import escape
valid_part = "<i> hello1 </i>" #needs escaping
invalid_part = "<i> hello2 </i>" #needs escaping
error = "{0} <span style='background-color:yellow'>{1}</span>".format(escape(valid_part),escape(invalid_part))
return render_to_response('my.html',{"error":error})
```

In template:

```
#my.html
{{ error|safe }}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the view part:

```
 'parts': {
   'valid1': mark_safe(valid1),
   'valid2': mark_safe(valid2),
   'invalid': invalid,
 }
```

In the template:

```
{{ parts.valid1 }} {{ parts.invalid }} {{ parts.valid2 }}
```

Comment: can i do it somehow without modifying the template django generates for the admin?

Comment: it's generated, i don't think it's a good idea to try to modify it

Comment: Yes of course, bat can you show it? Just for better understanding

Comment: I can't find the template. I think I found something that might be useful in the future https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates Thanks anyway